Algorithm to find k optimal representatives for subsets of a set with arbitrary cost function
Given a set of N points, I am required to split it into k subsets S1, ..., Sk. Each subset Si will have a representative Ri. I want to find these R1, ..., Rk to minimize an arbitrary cost function of the subset-members with respect to the cluster representative. Basically,
\min \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{Pj \in Si} cost(Pj, Ri)
where the cluster representative Ri is itself obtained from the cluster members by another arbitrary reduce function
Ri = reduce(Si)
I took inspiration from k-means clustering, and came up with the below algorithm, that I'm calling k-reduce clustering. I want to know if there is any algorithm or family of algorithms that does what I'm trying to do.
# Initialize using k random samples from S, could use better initialization
cluster_repr = random_samples(S, k) # list of k points
clusters = None

while True:

    # Step 1: Assignment
    old_clusters = clusters
    clusters = [[] for i in range(n)]
    for Pj in S:
        # assign s to the cluster that minimizes its cost wrt to the representative
        cluster_idx = argmin(
            cluster_repr,
            lambda Ri : cost_fn(Pj, Ri)
        )
        clusters[cluster_idx].append(Pj)

    # Step 2: Update step
    cluster_repr = [reduce_fn(clusters[i]) for i in range(n)]

    total_dist = None
    if old_clusters == clusters: break


May I first question the choice of k? How is it known a priori? A badly chosen k and randomly chosen representatives can lead to arbitrarily bad results. My first gut feeling is to start with DBSCAN, which is a great clustering algorithm that determines the number of clusters k on its own. Then, simply the average or the median according to the cost function could be selected in each cluster as a representative.

@Marcell, That's a good question. Indeed, it would be great if 'k' could be found automatically. I expect k to be small, so, I think it'd be okay to run the algorithm multiple times to find a good k. I just looked at DBSCAN. Perhaps, the tricky part here might be that the reduce_fn I'm interested in is more akin to a 'max' function. I'm more interested in the representatives Ri themselves, which need not lie anywhere in the 'center' of the subset. Would dbscan still be a good choice for a 'max'-like reduce function?

I believe dbscan is a very good choice for your task. dbscan needs one parameter, a threshold epsilon that decides whether two items are neighbors given their "distance" to each other. Your cost_fn() should be well suited to serve as distance, as you already are using it that way. You need to determine your epsilon experimentally, or by analyzing your data, which is usually not hard. Then there is no need to run dbscan multiple times.

The part where you choose a representative for each cluster I don't understand too well. To pick a maximum of a set, you need to define an order, which you haven't given any information about so far. What kind of data are we dealing with here?

@Marcell 'max'-like is an example. I'm expecting the details to be taken care of by the 'reduce_fn' function supplied by the user. But, for the case of 'max'-like, I'll be having data points in the form of short vectors, say: P1 = [a1, b1, c1, d1], ..., Pn = [an, bn, cn, dn]. Then, max_like(P1, ..., Pn) = [max(a1, ..., an), max(b1, ..., bn), max(c1, ..., cn), max(d1, ..., dn)]. Here, ai, bi, ci, di are all real numbers. 'max' is then the usual max over real numbers. But the reduce_fn will be the max_like function.

I wonder if dbscan's distance function needs to satisfy any assumptions which might be broken by the max_like function I intend to use. But, at this point, I think I'll give dbscan a try and report here. Thanks!

Without some assumptions about those functions, this problem is NP-hard.
Demonstration. Let's reduce 3DM to this. Take a 3-partite hypergraph with 3k nodes. Create a cost function cost(Pj, Ri) = ||Ri||. Create a reduce function that will map to a "representative" that has norm 1 for any triplet in the hypergraph, and otherwise will be very large. And now if there is a 3-matching, the optimal solution will be that 3-matching, and we've reduced a known NP-complete problem (in fact one of Karp's original 21) to this one.
In general we don't know a way to verify that a solution is optimal in polynomial time. So we don't know that your problem is in P. Therefore the best that we know how to prove is that it is NP-hard.

Very interesting! So, I'll either have to put some constraints on cost and reduce. Or find a heuristic and check that it works well for my use cases.

@digikar Exactly. And if you put constraints, the structure of those constraints must be key to how the search works.
